# Single assignment for basic types in C++

Tags: c++

I'd like to create a "single assignment" wrapper for basic types (such as int) that talks like an int, walks like an int, smells like an int, but can only be modified or assigned to at most once (like in some pure functional languages). For example (copy constructor omitted to keep the example simple):

```
template<class T>
struct SA {
    SA<T>(T init) : wasAssigned(false) {
        val = tmp = init;
    }
    SA<T> & operator=(const T& other) {
        if (!wasAssigned) {
            if (val != tmp) {
                val = tmp;
            } else {
                val = tmp = other;
            }
            wasAssigned = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    operator T& () {
        if (!wasAssigned && (val != tmp)) {
            wasAssigned = true;
            val = tmp;
        } else {
            tmp = val;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
private:
    bool wasAssigned;
    T val, tmp;
};
```

This is close, but not perfect. It relies on the val/tmp equality test to detect changes, and fails in this case:

```
SA<int> i(3);
cin >> i;
i = 5;
```

Iff the `cin >> i` assigns the same value as the initial value (3), i will be 5 at the end. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm sorry for blurting out the obvious question, but I can't stop myself: Why do you need this?

Comment: Say you want to let a value be changed only by the first RPC call, or let a user modify a value only if it wasn't locked down through a command line argument, etc... There's obviously ways to do it without Single Assignment. I want to know if the concept can be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following might work, although I'm not 100% sure about the side-effects. Basically returning a reference to `tmp` on all but the first call that gets a non-const reference, plus `const` methods for read-only access.

```
operator T& () {
  if (wasAssigned) {
    tmp = val;
    return tmp;
  } else {
    wasAssigned = true;
    return val;
  }
}

operator const T& () const {
  return val;
}

operator T () const {
  return val;
}
```

Comment: `tmp` is the same as it was in the OP's code, a member of the class.

Comment: That won't work. If you pass a freshly created (but not assigned) object to cout for example, "operator T&" will be called, and since wasAssigned is set to true, you'll be stuck with the initialized value.

Comment: @Gabriel: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `cout` takes basic data types by value, so it would call `operator T`, not `operator T&`.